# Why does Facebook's Android app scroll so smoothly

Tags: android, facebook, listview, smoothing

Facebook has the most smooth UI in my Android Phone, and I am wondering how can they do that.

While I am writing my demo, ListView with images always seems to be laggy, while facebook's new feed activity behaviors so amazing.

Anyone can tell me whether the Facebook App uses native ListView but with some improvement, or just rewrite the whole view for better performance?

EDIT: I have already used the caching strategy such as using async threads, caching ViewHolder as tag and storing images in memory for acceleration, while I still feel laggy. I do really want to know how did facebook engineers do that, they are really brilliant

Comment: I don't know if anyone other than a Facebook mobile developer will be able to answer this question for you.

Comment: Try enabling hardware acceleration in your manifest file to see if that makes a difference

Comment: @xbonez In fact, I have used different devices to test the app, some of which does not have the ability to do hardware acceleration at all. But the facebook app still behaviors much better than other apps.

Comment: If you show some code (maybe github, pastebin or gist) may be able to see if there is any possible bottlenecks in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hooking the device up to adb, open DDMS and press the method profiling button, then start scrolling a bunch for a few seconds. [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) will open and you see what is using up all the CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a ListView before, but if I had to guess maybe they are retrieving the results and then caching them, whereas you're querying for the results everytime and not caching them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have used the caching strategy as Google I/O 2009 presented. Also I do store images in memory for acceleration, while I still feel laggy. Albeit the simplest listview with only texts scrolls really smooth.